# Twillio reply to message

Tags: twilio

I have this code:

```
require dirname(__FILE__)."/twilio/services/Twilio.php"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($option['twilioAccountSid'], $option['twilioAuthToken']); 

$client->account->sms_messages->create($option['twilioFrom'], 
    $to, 
    'Will you attend?',
    array('StatusCallback'=>'http://domain.com/callback.php'));
```

callback.php:

```
file_put_contents('/twilio.log', print_r(array($_REQUEST), true) . PHP_EOL );
```

The scenario is the following. I send the message "Will you attend?" $to +155555555. When they reply back, I want to insert that answer into a database.

I thought that callback.php will be called when they reply with a message, and I'll have the variable $_REQUEST['body'] with their answer, along with other variables, but that's not the case. In twilio.log I have only a confirmation that I sent the message.

**How to I grab the response message into a php file for latter use with a database?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/ Select the number you use. Look next to **Messaging** for **Request URL** . There you have to put your callback and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

No, its working the way its supposed to. The callback doesn't have anything to do with the user responding to the SMS, its Twilio's response to processing your outgoing message.

One solution for you might be to use cookies if you need to essential track a conversation.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/tracking-conversations

On the other hand, if the *only* communication you expect to get back is either a yes or no, having the calling number and the reply maybe enough for you, even without using cookies.

Comment: I work with OpenVBX and in their applets the reply from a user can be grabbed in twiml.php the same file that sends them a message. I know is posible, I just find a little confusing the documentation on Twilio.