# Reply on Twilio number not working

Tags: php, sms, twilio, phone-number, twilio-php

I am receiving message from my Twilio account (Trial) with having number 001122. But when I am replying to this number in India (already setting my webhook php url in - MESSAGE COMES IN) from my verified number. Message not sending, it says:

> Phone Number Formatted Incorrectly

What else I need to change into my account?

I taken reference from [Twillio reply to message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703958/twillio-reply-to-message) but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I checked you Stack Overflow account, and your company appears to be based in India, so my guess is that you're sending SMS messages in India.

There are a few [limitations when sending SMS messages from Twilio in India](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices) and you have come across one of them. The sending number, from your Twilio account, is not maintained and the message appears to come from a 6 digit number. The issue is that replying to that number will not get sent to your Twilio number because it isn't your Twilio number.

So, you cannot have users reply directly back to your messages, they have to send them directly to your number.

I recommend you read:

- [The limitations of sending SMS to Indian mobile devices](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices)
- [The Twilio guidelines for sending SMS messages to India](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/in)

Comment: Thanks for responding, Looking into the 2 url.